# runtime exception in jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js in asp.net mvc4

Tags: jquery, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am converting a mvc4 app to mobile friendly one.  I have installed jquery.mobile and jquery.mobile.mvc through nuget

in my layout.mobile.cshtml the code is as follows

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Mobile/Site.Mobile.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but when I run the app by setting user agent as Iphone I get the following exception even before the page gets loaded

```
Exception Description: ![Jscript run time error][1] in  $.mobile is undefined in jquery-mobile-1.2.0.js
```

I am new to mobile development using jquery.   And also can anyone tell me how to scale down the images when viewing in a mobile agent right now I am using the following code but when I use the mobile agent the images are as big as in desktop  I am using IE 8 and mvc4.  Please Help?

```
<head>
    @using System;
    @using System.Web;
    <title>@ViewBag.Title </title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Mobile/Site.Mobile.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/custom-theme/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Icons/icons.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      @System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css")
          @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you put a reference to the "main" Jquery?

See this example: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html

ALSO: you only need ONE jquery mobile. jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js is the "compressed" and optimized library, and jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js is the debuging one. Same thing as the "main" jquery.

Comment: Hi Thanks for this link.  Can you also pls tell me whether all the jquery functions I used in my web app project can be implemented for the mobile friendly pages which are in the same project with only the different extension

Comment: Well... If your want to know if all Jquery function can work on mobile, the answer is yes. If you want to use extension: it's depend of the extension and what she does. Sometimes, it will work, sometimes, not. You have to verify with every extensions that you use to see if it's will be compatible with Jquery mobile (or if will simply work on a mobile environment).